# how to properly execute custom node module as a function

Tags: node.js

Getting started with Node.
Put together a custom module, which parses an Excel file into a MongoDB:

```
exports.excelFileParser = function(fileName){
    if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');


    var mongodb = require('mongodb');

    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

    var url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/my_database';

        var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./uploads/' + fileName);

        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];

        var json_conversion = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
            } else {
                console.log('Connection established to', url);

                db.open(function(err, client){
                    client.createCollection("test_collection", function(err, col) {
                        client.collection("test_collection", function(err, col) {
                            {
                                json_conversion.forEach(function(record) {
                                    col.insert(record, function(err, result) {
                                        if(err) {
                                            console.log(err);
                                        }
                                        else {

                                        }
                                    });
                                })
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                console.log("finished");
                db.close();
            }
        });

};
```

In my server.js I require this module as follows:

```
var excelFileParser = require("excel-file-parser");
```

At a certain point in my node app, I need to execute the functionality of this module, and pass it a file name to be parsed.
When I try it this way:

```
excelFileParser(file.fieldname);
```

I get

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

exception.

What is the proper way to run my module from within server.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at your module:

```
exports.excelFileParser = function(fileName) {
    ...
}
```

When you call `require('excel-file-parser')` you basically get the `exports` object.

So to invoke the function you have created you need to call the function:

```
var myParser = require("excel-file-parser");
myParser.excelFileParser('filename');
```